# PrintWriter very slow flush() and print(). Multithreads and sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, printwriter

I have this weird problem with my (multithreaded) server when I get more than 500 players connected simultaneously, the PrinterWriter take more than 100 seconds or more (2 minutes) to finish flush() or print() sometimes.

Here is the code:

```
public static void send(Player p, String packet)
{   
    PrintWriter out = p.get_out();
    if(out != null && !packet.equals("") && !packet.equals(""+(char)0x00))
    {
        packet = Crypter.toUtf(packet);
        out.print((packet)+(char)0x00);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

the printWriter is something like this:

```
_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
_out = new PrintWriter(_socket.getOutputStream());
```

If I add the keyword synchronized to the send() method, the whole server starts to lag every 2 seconds, if I don't then some random player starts to lag for no reason.

Anyone have any idea ? Where is this coming from? What should I do?

Comment: Since you no control over the clients, you have to assume any number of clients could stop reading or be unacceptably slow.  When this happens you have to think about how you are going to handle this.  You should be able to flush to 500 connections in under 10 ms if your clients are reading data fast enough. i.e. the buffers always have free space. You can't let one slow client to slow down every other client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print writer is wrapped around a socket's output stream, so I'm going to guess and say that the socket's output buffer is full, and so the write/flush call will block until the buffer has enough room to accommodate the message being sent.

The socket send buffer may become full if data is being written to it faster than it can be transmitted to the client (or faster than the client can receive it).

**Edit:**

P.S.  If you're having scalability problems, it may be due to using java.io (which requires one thread per socket) instead of java.nio (in which case a single thread can detect and perform operations on those sockets which have pending data).  nio is intended to support applications which must scale to a large number of connections, but the programming model is more difficult.

Comment: Maybe you are right. My default buffer size is: 128 000 IN / 49 152 OUT. Is it enough ?   How much is enough ?

Comment: It's not so much about the buffer size, but about the rate you are writing to the socket, and the rate at which the data can be transmitted and received by the client.  If the first rate is greater than the second, then the caller will always end up blocking/waiting.  In this case, you might be trying to send too much data too quickly; reducing the update rate or the amount of data being sent could help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your send() method is static, so all threads that write to any socket are being syncrhonized on the containing class object. Make it non-static, then only threads that are writing to the same socket will be synchronized.

Comment: Although the method looks like a utility method which doesn't share any resources, so no synchronization appears necessary.  If more than one caller might manipulate a Player instance concurrently, then perhaps the callers should be responsible for synchronizing outside of the utility method, on some object such as the Player instance itself.

Comment: You are right! Thank you! The code is too big i'll have to change alot of things, but thank you. I hope it will fix the problem if it's just a threading problem.